# Encoding/Decoding Javascript in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I use the technique described here:
http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html

In a nutshell, one has a javascript file that looks like this, where the actual javascript is encoded:

```
document.write( unescape( 'escaped string' ) ); dF('encoded javascript');
```

I now want to run that same .js module under Nashorn, but Nashorn does not have a document object.  Therefore, I can not do document.write().

Note: It is well known that this technique is easily bypassed and people modest technical ability can still look at the actual code.  My use case does not require strong security so that is not a concern.  That said, Please consider answers on why one should not do this as off topic.  Thanks.

Comment: That's a terribly file: don't use `document.write`. It's not 1998, don't use JS patterns from over a decade ago. Anything that looks like that is pretty much guaranteed to be an attempt at phishing or other nasty business. (automatically deploying obfuscated code that you need to decode to even see what it does? yeah, let's not work with that)

Comment: You'll probably want to strip the `<script>` tags from that thing and `eval` the resulting code. Please show us the exact input string if you need further answers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that code breaks down into two parts:

1. Un-obfuscate the string via `unescape`.
2. Write the string out via `document.write.`

It sounds like you want to use the string directly for some reason.

You have at least two options:

1. You can *provide* a `document` object to the scripting engine with a `write` method that accepts a string. Then you can do with it what you like. (Or substitute `document.write` before evaluating the string with any function you want called.)
2. Remove the `document.write(` and the corresponding `)` at the end and have the engine evaluate the string and hand it to you directly as the result of `ScriptEngine#eval`.

Either way, you'll end up with a string that you can then do something with.